# looking for a smart and fast searching algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary, java-7

lets say i have 2 arrays of the objects which are mapped to each other in the following schemna:

array1 :

```
String [] prog_types1 = {"Program1","Program2","Program3","Program4"};
```

and array2 :

```
String [] prog_types2 ={"SubProgram1","SubProgram2","SubProgram3","SubProgram4",  
"SubProgram5","SubProgram6","SubProgram7","SubProgram8","SubProgram9","SubProgram10"};
```

as it understood from its names, prog_types2 is an extension for prog_types1, but has some repeated values, so the full mapping between these programs would looks liek this:

```
prog_types1     prog_types2
ProgramType1    SubProgramType1
ProgramType1    SubProgramType2
ProgramType1    SubProgramType7
ProgramType1    SubProgramType9
ProgramType2    SubProgramType12
ProgramType2    SubProgramType7
ProgramType2    SubProgramType9
ProgramType3    SubProgramType1
ProgramType3    SubProgramType2
ProgramType3    SubProgramType21
ProgramType3    SubProgramType27
ProgramType3    SubProgramType7
ProgramType5    SubProgramType12
ProgramType5    SubProgramType9
```

my question is : what is the best way to map these arrays to each other, from the perspective of faster processing and reuse?
I have implemented it as :

-- set of classes (class prog1 and prog2 and after put it into vector)...

-- hashtable with hashset

-- possible one more array

the way i am looking for should not consist of creating the same prog2 objects again for prog1 object, as it would be in all of the ways described earlier, but map it by the index position for example or in any other way.
just lookin for a nice algorythmical way to resolve it...

thanks in advance

p.s. it should be used within 1 package only between couple of classes and the main use of it would be a population of the prog2 types values based on the prog1 type value

p.s.2 java7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [MultiMap](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Guava Libraries, you could say:

```
Multimap<String, String> mmap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
mmap.put("Program1", "SubProgramType1");
mmap.put("Program1", "SubProgramType2");
// etc.

mmap.get("Program1")
```

would look like:

```
[SubProgramType1, SubProgramType2, SubProgramType7, SubProgramType9]
```

BTW, Hashtable is not used now for hashed collections, has been superceded by [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) :)

Comment: yeah looks like this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way would be a:

```
Map<String, List<String>> programs = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

with the strings in the first list as keys and the corresponding subprograms composing the value list. Now the mapping is obvious:

```
ProgramType1 -> [SubProgramType1, SubProgramType2, SubProgramType7, SubProgramType9]
ProgramType2 -> [SubProgramType12, SubProgramType7, SubProgramType9]
ProgramType3 -> [SubProgramType1, SubProgramType2, SubProgramType21, SubProgramType27, SubProgramType7]
ProgramType5 -> [SubProgramType12, SubProgramType9]
```

Comment: Even better: a [Guava `Multimap<String, String>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Comment: so what is the difference from Hashtable<String,Hashset<String>>?

Comment: @user1324100: Well it depends. Do you have any particular use for the value being a `Hashset` and not a simple `List`?

Answer (score 0):

Guava `ListMultimap`, that gives `List<E>`, not `Collection<E>` - little more pleasant.

```
private ListMultimap<String,Something> stuff = ArrayListMultimap.create();

// ...

public void add(String key, Something item) {
  stuff.put(key, item);
}

public List<Something> get(String key) {
  // might as well use the Lists convenience API while we're at it.
  return Lists.newArrayList(stuff.get(key));
}
```

http://www.coffee-bytes.com/2011/12/22/guava-multimaps

Answer (score 0):

btw, since i need :

-- separately use Program1 values

-- separately use SubProgram1 values

-- populate SubProgram1 values based on Program1 value

the easiest solution here would be to declare a double dimensional array with all the dublicates (as it dysplayed in full map schema) and for 1) and 2) populate data from it using non repeating algorythm and 3) loop cycle from 2nd dimension

so no reason to declare 3 objects, huge memory save and nice approach.
i am giving myself a star for it:)